# Front suspension seized - what can I do

Tags: suspension

I have mistreated my bike and now am regretting it. The front forks are completely stuck. I took the end cap off the forks there's a bolt there but it's like 12 inches deep. Where the heck can I buy a 12inch hex key? because I've not been able to get anything long enough I don't even know what size hex key. It's not possible to take it apart from the bottom am sure because it just tapers off then attaches to the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say where you live (what country?), so you may not have this particular option for a store, but you could use a 3/8" drive extension:

http://www.lowes.com/pd_337346-22328-85817_1z0wcg7__?productId=3380286&pl=1

With a 3/8" drive hex driver:

http://www.lowes.com/pd_338623-22328-85226_0__?productId=3387790

(You might also be able to find a T-handle hex driver that is long enough, although a quick google search didn't turn one up for me.)

This is of course assuming the base of the hex driver will fit into your fork tube, which it may not, you will have to check.
Also, before trying to loosen anything you should spray the bolt / any seized parts with penetrating oil (like WD-40 or PB Blaster) & let it sit for a while. That alone might end up being enough to free the stuck parts.

If you do get it apart, you should really consider doing a proper overhaul on it & determine if it is even fixable / worth fixing.